# how to change between two div's in an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to have an iframe with my cv in it, but you need to have the code to see it. I want to this with an iframe to change between two divs without going to another page or a reload. The code wil be a sha hash of an id and a salt.

Is it possible to change between two divs in an iframe, or are there another and better selutions for this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not use AJAX instead of an iframe?

Comment: if the code to enter require too much time and effort, some may just not even request it , a capcha could be used and is commun enough to be almost unnoticed ...

Comment: thanks for the comments, my idea was more like only for compenies or the ones how need to see it and not public for anyone. I wanted a form where they fill there compeny name in and send me an email. than i will generate a sha hash and send it back. with that they can login. that was the hole idea. or is it to much